# Count unique slices in a ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D integer tensor `X` with `X.shape=(m, n, k)`

I'd like to treat `X` as a `(m, n)` matrix with entries that are `k` sized integer vectors and count how many such unique entries are in each row.
So for example

```
>>> X
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 1, 2],
        [1, 2, 3],
        [1, 2, 3]],
       [[3, 4, 5],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [5, 6, 7],
        [6, 7, 8]]])
>>> X.shape
(2, 4, 3)

>>> count_unique(X)
[2, 4]
```

Since in the first row of the tensor there are 2 unique vectors and in the second row there are 4

Bonus points for returning the actual unique vectors, e.g.

```
>>> get_unique(X)
[[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]],\
[3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8]]]
```

My solution (partially vectorized) for the first question

```
count_unique = lambda X: [len(np.unique(row, axis=0)) for row in X]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
unique_list = []
for sublist in X:
    tmp_unique_list =  []
    for element in sublist:
        if element not in tmp_unique_list:
            tmp_unique_list.append(element)
    unique_list.append(tmp_unique_list)
```

Output:

```
> unique list
  [[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3]], [[3, 4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [6, 7, 8]]]
```

And the count:

```
> [len(elem) for elem in unique_list]
[2, 4]
```